# VC generalization bound extended to other types of target functions

Tags: machine-learning, vc-dimension

In Y. S. Abu-Mostafa's book "Learning from Data", he mentions on page 55 after deriving the VC generalization bound for a binary target function that "it can be extended to other types of target functions". I have looked online for quite a bit but it's really not clear to me how that should work. I'm particularly interested in continuous target functions, where hypothesis $h \in \mathcal{H}$ maps input space $\mathcal{X}$ to $\mathbb{R}^N$, rather than classifications. But I don't see how shattering could be adapted for these target functions.

Comment: Maybe the sets allowed to use for shattering are restricted to some geometric families, such as halfspaces. Such questions are studied in learning theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pseudo dimension and fat shattering dimension are (some of the) analogue of VC dimension in the regression setting. See [https://ttic.uchicago.edu/~tewari/lectures/lecture15.pdf](https://ttic.uchicago.edu/%7Etewari/lectures/lecture15.pdf) (section 3)

Answer (score 1):

Daniely et al had some works on the subject back in 2012--2015.

In particular, it is referred to (there) as "multiclass learning".
Here are two works on this:

[Multiclass learnability and the ERM principle](https://arxiv.org/abs/1308.2893)

[Multiclass Learning Approaches: A Theoretical Comparison with Implications](https://arxiv.org/abs/1205.6432)

Unfortunately, my knowledge of this is limited to knowing the authors personally, so I can't really give any technical details :)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I looked into them but I fail to see how multiclass prediction relates to VC dimensions of continuous functions rather than classifications.

Comment: @ste - I may be completely off. From the conversations I had with Amit Daniely, he mentioned that what they do was essentially to extend the idea of VC dimension to multiclasses. But it's entirely possible I misunderstood.

Comment: But as I say in the OP, I'm not looking for classification but for regression. How is multiclassing a case of regression?

Comment: I don't see where you mention regression in the OP. Anyway, as I mentioned: I know next to nothing about this topic. The OP mentions extending VC beyond the binary setting, and that rang a bell for me, so I wrote what little I know.
If you want me to delete the answer, let me know.